# Linq Join using Lambda in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

How do I use C# lambda expression with "=>" in VB.NET?

Following is the C# code:

```
var marketValues = req.SelectedAccounts.Join(assetAllocations, a1 => a1.ModelCode, a2 => a2.APLID, (a1, a2) =>
new { a1, a2 }).Select(o => new
{
MarketValue = o.a1.MarketValue,
AssetAllocationName = o.a2.AssetAllocationName,
AccountID = o.a1.AccountID,
Weight = o.a2.Weight,
MarketValueWeight = ((o.a1.MarketValue * o.a2.Weight) / 100)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: `Are there any examples present on the net?` What does this suppose to mean? *I am too lazy to google, do it for me?*

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I have been trying since 2 hrs. I asked for help.

Comment: All the converting websites don't work.

Comment: Did you try this ? http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Yeah I tried this too.. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be something like:

```
Dim marketValues = req.SelectedAccounts.Join(assetAllocations, 
                                             Function(a1) a1.ModelCode, 
                                             Function(a2) a2.APLID, 
                                             Function(a1, a2) New With { a1, a2 }) _
                                       .Select(Function(o) New With 
                                       { 
                                            Key .MarketValue = o.a1.MarketValue, _
                                            Key .AssetAllocationName = o.a2.AssetAllocationName, _
                                            Key .AccountID = o.a1.AccountID, _
                                            Key .Weight = o.a2.Weight, _
                                            Key .MarketValueWeight = ((o.a1.MarketValue * o.a2.Weight) / 100) 
                                        }).ToList()
```

Comment: That works perfectly... I was using From instead of With. Thanks.